# Where do the variables in a (set theory) interpretation come from?

Tags: set-theory

I'm reading Paul J. Cohen's book "Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis" and on page 12 he starts introducing the concept of a model.

He starts with $S$ a collection of statements with constants $c_\alpha$, $\alpha \in I$ and relation symbols $R_\beta$, $\beta \in J$.

Next he introduces $M$ a non-empty set and a mapping $c_\alpha \rightarrow \bar{c}_\alpha$ where the $\bar{c}_\alpha \in M$ and a mapping from each $R_\beta$ to $M \times M \times ... \times M$ (where a $k$-ary relation maps to a $k$ fold product).

So far, I'm good - he is basically saying let's start with an abstract system and map it to something "concrete" (e.g. numbers).

Then, he goes on to introduce truth criteria. In there he suddenly introduces variables $\bar{x}_1, ..., \bar{x}_n$ which are elements of $M$.

My question is: where did the $\bar{x}_1, ..., \bar{x}_n$ come from? Is $M$ a tuple consisting of a set of constants and a set of variables? I don't see a place for variables in $M$ because its merely a set of objects where we are going to check the truth value of the statements in $S$.

Comment: Why are you reading Cohen's book?????

Comment: @AsafKaragila should I not? I found it in a bookstore, its at topic I'm interested in, and I started a little study ground about it.

Comment: @roundsquare If Asaf means this is a bad book, then I disagree. But I think it's more likely that he means one or both of (1) It is a bad place to learn/study forcing. (2) It is a bad book for a beginner to learn logic from. I agree strongly with (1): forcing was obviously very new at the time and various aspects of Cohen's exposition quickly became obsolete. As for (2), the rest of the book is good IMO but I'd hesitate to recommend it to a beginner since it's quite brief. But this is much less clear-cut to me than (1).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thanks. Re: (2) I'm not a beginner so much as rusty - and I gotta be honest, his rough exposition (so far) is nice since it requires me to work out and understand the details. Re: (1) as we get to forcing, that's a good point. We'll probably find other sources as we get there to make sure we're up to date. Any recommendations?

Comment: @roundsquare If you like brief, Nik Weaver’s Forcing for Mathematicians goes from 0 to independence of CH in 50 pages. It is also pretty clear about the metamathematics and gets most of its mileage from sacrificing generality and topics that aren’t strictly necessary (e.g. constructibilty). There are also also good non rigorous expository notes by Chow and by Easwaran. Then there’s more standard references like Kunen, Jech, and Halbeisen. There have been some mse posts about learning forcing that you can search for.

Comment: @roundsquare Also on the brief side is the old Schoenfield article “unramified forcing” which is probably the first review of what’s now the standard approach. Heard good things but never been through it myself...

Comment: I learned  Forcing & Iterated Forcing from Ch. 7 & 8 of Kunen's Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs, 1st  edition, which I think is a very clear presentation. (I also had 2 excellent teachers, William Weiss & Franklin Tall.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are not part of the model, they are part of the syntax for formulas in a given language. However in a model, you can assign elements of the model to the variables. In Cohen’s book, variables are denoted $x_i$ whereas their values in a particular variable assignment are denoted $\bar x_i$.

The distinction between constant symbols and variables is that the interpretation of the constants is part of the model itself, whereas the variable assignment is something separate and we can assign the variables to anything we want in the context of a single model.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense to me in the context of a statement like $\forall x, x + 0 = x$ because then I can write $\forall \bar{x}, \bar{x} + \bar{0} = \bar{x}$ and see if that's true in $M$ by seeing if $\bar{0}$ really is the additive identity in $M$. But, he also writes that if $x_i=x_j$ is a statement in S then $\bar{x}_i=\bar{x}_j$ should be true in $M$ (for $M$ to be a model).

Comment: I don’t see where he says that. The definition of a model of $S$ that I see on pg 13 only pertains to statements. There is no notion of a formula with free variables being “true in $M$”, only true in $M$ at some variable assignment. Likewise it doesn’t make strict sense to say $\bar x_i=\bar x_j$ is true in $M$. Those are already elements of $M$, so it’s just true or false in the informal sense.

Comment: That said, after the formalities are down, we often get sloppy, using the same symbols for constant symbols, variables, and their interpretations and leaving it up to the reader to keep things straight based on the context, which, after some experience, is often clearer in practice than having a bunch of different barred and unbarred c’s and x’s flying around.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I mean in the definition of truth value, point 1 where it says "If $A$ is of the form $x_i = x_j$ ... then A is true at $\bar{x}_1, ..., \bar{x}_n$ if $\bar{x}_i = \bar{x}_j$". Am I reading it too literally? Am I supposed to interpret this as _part_ of a statement instead of a complete statement e.g. $R(x_i, x_j) \land R(x_j, x_i) \rightarrow x_i = x_j$ which would I could verify in the model $M$ if $R$ corresponds to the subset of $M \times M$ that corresponds to $\leq$.

Comment: Your point about how things get sloppy after a bit is well taken. I just want to make sure I understand the framework I'm working in before I get sloppy.

Comment: Yeah, it’s important to get it straight first. I don’t see a problem with the statement you just quoted. The formula $x_1=x_2$ is true in some model at some variable assignment if and only if the variable assignment assigns them to the same thing. In other words, iff $\bar x_1=\bar x_2$. I don’t see how adding the part about $R$ changes anything. I think you might be implicitly assuming we are universally quantifying over the variables here which is not the case... we are considering various assignments for them.

Comment: For instance your remark there about $R$ being interpreted as an ordering relation would imply that the statement is true in the model at *every* possible variable assignment, which is equivalent to the universal quantification of the formula (which has no free variables) being true in the model. (Whereas being true at a particular variable assignment just means that particular assignment doesn’t refute the fact that $R$ has the anti symmetry property.)

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. I was thinking of the variables the way I was thinking about the constants. I went back realized that the statements can't have free variables and then it made sense - unlike constants where $c_1$ has a constant meaning, in each statement $x_1$ only has meaning in that statement.